# Java Inheritence behaviour

Tags: java

There is a particular code in java that I am trying to understand,

```
package test;

public class TestDerived extends Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        TestDerived td = new TestDerived();
        Test t = new Test();//Second call
        System.out.println(td.science);
    }

    TestDerived()
    {
        super();//First call
        showMyAttribute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void showMyAttribute()
    {
        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + " : " + math);
    }

    int math = 10;
}

class Test {

    Test()
    {
        showMyAttribute();
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

    protected void showMyAttribute()
    {
        System.out.println(getClass().getName() + " : " + science);
    }

    int science = 9;
}
```

when I run it, I get the following output,

```
test.TestDerived : 0
Test
test.TestDerived : 10
test.Test : 9
Test
9
```

I have not completely understood this behaviour of java. By looking at the properties of java, i feel it has something to do with the runtime polymorphism, though i am not sure whether i am right, and clueless about how this output is generated. Firstly when a super method is called using the constructor super, it gives the value `0` . Then when i call the constructor of super class explicitly in the main method, i get a proper value. Again later when i print the value of variable `science` using the sub-class object, it gives the correct value. What is the difference when I call it from the constructor of subclass using super(), and when call it explicitly. I need help in understanding this.

Comment: Just do it @rgettman.

Comment: works like this: `super` first, then members init, then constructor content.

Comment: i modified the question a bit